# How to add crypto to a nodejs build?

Tags: node.js

"It is possible for Node.js to be built without including support for the crypto module."

How can I add crypto to Node.js or choose how to build with ?

I know there is a npm package with the name "crypto" but there are packages who needs the crypto built-in.

Answer (score 0):

By default nodejs official packages are built with all defaults native packages.

But in some case you can experiment error trying to load (using `require`) a excluded module using a custom build (for example without OpenSSL support).

The ['crypto'](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto) npm module is an external module with a different interface and functions... and for his name it can conflicts with node's native one.

Comment: I updated nodejs with : 
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable 
So I guess it's an official package.
When I use "npm ls" I haven't crypto in the list, so I guess I didn't install the crypto package.

Comment: is a native package, so it is not shown in npm list. try with `require('crypto')`

Answer (score 0):

Alternative of crypto is bcrypt and grunt-openssl

Comment: "there are packages who needs the crypto built-in" it means I have some package which have require('crypto') so I don't think it will fix it :(

Comment: Yes I understand that crypto is default module of node.If you like to change the crypt module name is something else and add in the node_modules.